# How to make images fading using animate().alpha().setDuration() in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, animation

I have made the image fade once and display the second one. How do I do the same for the second image being displayed and onclick it fading and displaying the first image again? I tried ysing the fade and refade, but one does not work.

**Here is the XML**

```
            <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/imageView2"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             app:srcCompat="@drawable/a"
             android:onClick="fade"
             android:alpha="1" />

            <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/imageView1"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             app:srcCompat="@drawable/b"
             android:onClick="refade"
             android:alpha="1" />
```

**Here is the Java code:**

```
public void fade(View view){

    ImageView s1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    s1.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);

    Log.i("Infor", "The first image started fading");

    ImageView s2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    s2.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);

    Log.i("Infor", "The second appeared");
}


public void refade(View view){

    ImageView s2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    s2.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(1000);

    Log.i("Oiii", "The second image started fading");

    ImageView s1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    s1.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);

    Log.i("Oiii", "The first appeared");
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `fade` method on `onClick` of both imageview instead of `refade` in second.

Comment: That was a typo.. Initially while I was working on android studio I randomly named then fade and grade, I changed the name just to make it sound meaningful. Thank you @Heisen-Berg